# Can we add a column to a sharepoint list having data using powershell

Tags: list, powershell, column, document

Can we add a column to a sharepoint list having data using powershell without effecting anything in the sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

You can yes. It would simply add the new column to the list, existing list items would have no value for the field until someone edits the item. New items the field will be available for users.